# error in mysql_select_db() while connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql2.000webhost.com","a1750280_nasim12","demo nasim","a1750280_nasim12");
if($con)
{
mysql_select_db(a1750280_nasim12, $con);
}
?>
```

The response from the server I am getting is

> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid
>   MySQL-Link resource in /home/a1750280/public_html/index.php on line 69

I am very much sure and checked that `$con` works fine.

Comment: try calling mysql_select_db w/out the (optional) conn parameter

Comment: It should be quoted as it is a string

Comment: use `$con->select_db("database_name");` since you are using `mysqli`

Comment: SIDE NOTE: never share your database host name, username and password in the questions :)

Comment: You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions.

Comment: `error in mysql_select_db()` is this right or a typo or is `mysqli_connect` a typo ?

Answer (score 3):

You are  mixing the mysqli (note the **i**) and the mysql (note the **LACK** of an i) libraries. The two libraries are **NOT** interchangable. Operations/results/handles from one are **NOT** useable in the other.

Your select_db call should be converted to use the mysqli (**WITH** an `i`) library instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password");
if($con)
{
    $con->select_db("database_name");
}
?>
```

You need to use `$con->select_db("database_name");` or `mysqli_select_db($con, "database_name")` since you are using `mysqli` but not `mysql`

Comment: Please, explain the problem, rather than just posting a code.

Comment: Explained it. See the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

old way

```
mysql_select_db(a1750280_nasim12, $con);
```

change to new way

```
mysqli_select_db($con, "a1750280_nasim12");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php